# How to map multiple properties to arrays in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an array of objects like:

```
const data: any[] = [
     { x: 1, y: 1 },
     { x: 2, y: 2 },
     { x: 3, y: 4 },
     { x: 4, y: 6 }
];

// get x as array
from(d).pipe(map(m => m.x), toArray()).subscribe(x => ...);
```

And would like to map it to something like below to use it in `Plotly`

```
{
  x: [1,2,3,4],
  y: [1,2,4,6]
}
```

Of course, I could duplicate the pipe above to get y values, but this would be different subscriptions. Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use some ES6 magic here. We will be making use of the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). In a way, we are sort of transposing this array of objects.

```js
const data = [
     { x: 1, y: 1 },
     { x: 2, y: 2 },
     { x: 3, y: 4 },
     { x: 4, y: 6 }
];

const result = Object.assign(...Object.keys(data[0]).map(key =>
  ({ [key]: data.map( o => o[key] ) })
));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wow, I have to check out what is happening inside this magic. But I had to add the target `Object.assign({},...` to compile it. Thank you!

Comment: @alex555 Yeah, I admit this one might be a bit hard to read! trichetriche's solution seems the most readable amongst all the answers here!

Answer (score 3):

Not related to RxJS, it's just plain JS.

Use `reduce` as follows :

```js
const data = [
     { x: 1, y: 1 },
     { x: 2, y: 2 },
     { x: 3, y: 4 },
     { x: 4, y: 6 }
];

const plotly = data.reduce((p, n) => ({ 
  x: [...p.x, n.x], 
  y: [...p.y, n.y]
}), { 
  x: [], 
  y: []
});

console.log(plotly);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rxjs [reduce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html) instead

```
from(this.data).pipe(
  reduce((acc, m) => {
    acc.x.push(m.x);
    acc.y.push(m.y);
    return acc
  }, {x: [], y: []})).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gldpxy